# Loop in query function without "while"

Tags: php, mysql, row

Is it possible to show all rows with the properties from my query using only different last function. Something different from fetch_object();?

here is my query:

```
$dbo_training = $db->query("select * from tabela where id='$tr'")->fetch_object();
```

which is showing me only one row...

Comment: *Why* do you want to avoid looping using `while`?

Comment: I asked myself the same question as eggyal. It's a real need or you asked just out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i completley understand you but if what you want is an array of all the results, the method `fetch_object()` only returns the first row by definition. try using `fetch_assoc()` to get an array containing all the results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what ORM you are using but with PDO (the PHP standard database accessor) you have to call `fetchAll()` to do that. If you are using your own library you should have a look to [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetchall.php) which is very powerful!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using [mysqli::fetch_object()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php). If so, you might want to have a look at [mysqli::fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) which »Fetches all result rows as an associative array, a numeric array, or both« (but apparently not as array of objects…) If you need the objects, you'll probably have to stick to a while loop. (And there is nothing bad about a while loop per se)

Comment: fetch_all, fetch_assoc give me zero results. Do You recomend this solution?

 for($i=0; $i<$dbo_training->num_rows; $i++) {

Comment: I don't see how a for-loop is supposed to be any better than a while loop. You can do it - but that doesn't make it a good solution.